# Template function is not instantiated

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template <typename Collection>
string UniverseOut(const Collection& c) {
    stringstream res;
    bool is_first = true;

    for (auto& i : c) {
        if (!is_first) res << ',';

        is_first = false;
        res << i;
    }

    return res.str();
}

template <typename First, typename Second>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const pair<First, Second>& p) {
    return out << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ')';
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const map <Key, Value>& m){
    return out << '[' << UniverseOut(m) << ']';
}


int main()
{
    map<int, int> m{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};
    cout << m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio this code doesn't compile: `C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::pair<const int, int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`
but in the online compiler "onlinegdb" the code compiles and works as I expect.
Why is template function for `const std::pair<const int, int>` is not instantiated?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: GDBOnline is a nide tool, but here's a better one for a job like this: https://godbolt.org/z/1zG5zhrzf With Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer, you can look at your program as compiled with many different compilers and options. I just have it running the program since the problem's a compiler error, but if they all compiled you could compare the generated assembly output, spit out syntax trees, run sanitizers, and a smurfload of other things I've either never done or forgot I did.

Comment: Interesting.  With the settings I used, default compiler options, Visual Studio compiles and runs, GCC and Clang reject. We might be playing compiler version/option Whack-A-Mole.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm tested this code in default projects in VS2019 and VS2022, code doesn't compile. Also i compiled this code in gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
`gcc main.cpp -lstdc++ -o main`
code compiles

Comment: I used gobbolt.org. It compiles well with gcc 11.3 but not with gcc 12.1/12.2. But if I change the order code like this https://godbolt.org/z/xYhv98Y9h, it works.

Comment: Lol, forward declaration of this template function really helped. This is very strange behavior for me.

Comment: With you on that. Leaving this to the language lawyers.

Comment: ADL won't found `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<First, Second>&)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to `std::pair` not having a `<<` overload to any stream type, thus it can't 'put' a `std::pair` into the `std::stringstream` (which you have tried on the last line of the for-loop withing `UniverseOut`).

If you rearrange the code to have the `<<` overload for `std::pair`, above `UniverseOut`, then it can resolve the overload for `std::pair` types an 'put' `std::pair` in any `std::ostream` type (which [`std::stringstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) inherits from).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

template <typename First, typename Second>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair<First, Second>& p)
{ return out << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ')'; }

template <typename Collection>
std::string UniverseOut(const Collection& c) 
{
    std::stringstream res;
    bool is_first = true;

    for (auto& i : c) 
    {
        if (!is_first) 
            res << ',';

        is_first = false;
        res << i;
    }

    return res.str();
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::map<Key, Value>& m)
{ return out << '[' << UniverseOut(m) << ']'; }


int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```bash
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

[Working Demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/4zcefoevh)
[Failed Demo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/5cxf8r1e6)
(The errors stated that the overload of `<<` for `std::pair` could not be found)